# Will EF Dbcontext query for an entity that's already been loaded into the context?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm using EF code first with lazy loading and change tracking enabled. I thought I have read, and was under the assumption, that the dbcontext will not run an SQL query for an entity that was already loaded. This was mentioned as part of an article of lazy loading I was reading, but does this not also apply to straight up queries?

I have the following:

```
        // 1 query
        List<Form> forms = _formService.GetList();
        //1 query
        Form form = _formService.GetOne(x => x.Id == formId);
```

The service just wraps the context, no crazy voodoo going on underneath. Upon using glimpse to see the SQL. The page registered two separate queries, exactly as they were shown above, despite the first query including the POCO for the second one. Is Glimpse misleading me, or am I misunderstanding how the DBContext works?

Edit: The context is scoped to per HTTP request, so only one context for my API. However, just to confirm what Eric J mentioned I tried this code:

```
        DbContext db = new DbContext();
        List<Form> forms = db.Forms.ToList();
        Form form = db.Forms.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == formId);
```

To make sure there wasn't a problem in my API, and Glimpse still tells me the same thing. 2 queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the ***wrong*** method for finding an entity **that is already loaded** by your `DbContext`.

Instead of using `FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == formId)` you must use `Find(formId)`. `Find` method will look into the context to check if an entity with the same type and key you are looking for is already loaded:

- if it finds it then no SQL query will be sent to your databse
- if not then it will hit the database and load your entity

Comment: Interesting, that certainly wasn't mentioned in the article. Is it still correct that when referencing at lazily loaded entities, for instance say a department on an employee entity, when it gets to the second employee of the same department, it would not re-issue a query for the same department again?

Comment: It will not use a SQL query to load an entity that is already loaded through a navigational property as long as you use the same DbContext.